# Are Resource Attributes 'immutable' in the OTEL-Spec. SDK?

Tags: prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry

I am new to using OTEL. Upon reading some documentation, I found an interesting piece that has generated some doubts in my understanding of OTEL Resources.

From the link: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/resource/sdk.md

I see that it says resources are "immutable", for clarification, does this apply only to the resources' keys and attributes, or only keys?

If it is only for the keys, would anyone have an example where they use resources that get their attributes updated? I have been trying to find some of this in the web but so far all of the examples I have seen only have the same values without updates.

Answer (score 0):

The whole resource is immutable. That applies to the collection of attributes and the schema url. The attributes themselves are also immutable. This applies to both key and value. If you need to change either, you need to create a new attribute. This new attribute will then have to be added to a new resource. Note, that there are methods to merge an existing resource into a new one while adding attributes.

You can see this in the Java implementation as an example. The relevant code pieces are [io.opentelemetry.sdk.resources.Resource](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk/common/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/resources/Resource.java) and [io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/api/all/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/api/common/Attributes.java).

Comment: Great to know that, thank you for your the helpful information and links!